# Erro ao instalar o jdbc oracle no eclipse

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdbc

Estou encontrando impedimentos na instalação do jdbc do oracle.

**Tela**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> Error reading file
>   C:\Users\alex.jose.silva.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc14\10.2.0.3.0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar
>   C:\Users\alex.jose.silva.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc14\10.2.0.3.0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar
>   (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

**Comando**

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=o
>   jdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.x.x.x -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=ojdbc14.jar -DgeneratePom=true

**Resposta do comando**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Pow.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>br.com.devmedia</groupId>
   <artifactId>crud_cadastro_cliente</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>crud_cadastro_cliente Maven Webapp</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.1</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
         <version>1.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
         <version>1.8</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
         <classifier>tests</classifier>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
         <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
         <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId>
         <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
         <version>5.1.6</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>     


   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <finalName>crud_cadastro_cliente</finalName>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
               <path>/</path>
               <port>8080</port>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Comment: como está seu pom.xml ?

Comment: adicionei o pow.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
   <version>10.2.0.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

> Error reading file
>   C:\Users\alex.jose.silva.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc14\10.2.0.3.0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar
>   C:\Users\alex.jose.silva.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc14\10.2.0.3.0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar
>   (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

O mavem está tratando **10.2.0.3.0** como  um nome de uma pasta o correto seria seria ser sub pastas onde o mavem organiza cada versão das suas **libs**.

> Error reading file
>   C:\Users\alex.jose.silva.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc14\10\2\0\3\0\ojdbc14-10.2.0.3.0.jar

veja o erro !!

> (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

se você instalou driver ojdbc14 manualmente organize corretamente a pasta e sub pasta que vai funcionar que vai funcionar.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.x.x.x -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=C:\Users\alex.jose\ojdbc14\ojdbc14.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

**C:\Users\alex.jose\ojdbc14\ojdbc14.jar** é onde fica seu driver no seu disco..

Answer (score 0):

Conseguir resolver usando dois passos:

1. Executando o comando:

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Users\alex.jose.silva\Dow
>   nloads\ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7
>   -Dversion=12.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

2. Adicionar ao pow.xml:

   ```
      <dependency>
             <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
             <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
             <version>12.1.0</version>
      </dependency>
   ```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: isso mesmo!! que bom que deu certo..